# create req.cookie / access document.cookie

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies

I have created a cookie in express/node.js

```
var express = require('express');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')

var app = express();

app.use(cookieParser())
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  // check if client sent cookie
  var cookie = req.cookies.mainCookie;
  if (cookie === undefined){
    // no: set a new cookie
    var randomNumber=Math.random().toString();
    randomNumber=randomNumber.substring(2,randomNumber.length);
    res.cookie('cookieName',randomNumber, {
      maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24
      httpOnly: true
    });
    console.log('cookie created successfully', randomNumber);
  } else {
    // yes, cookie was already present
    console.log('cookie exists', cookie);
  }
  next();
});
```

then, I can access this cookie, like `req.cookie` but can't do `document.cookie` in front-end.
I would like to access it in front-end (JavaScript) Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set:

```
httpOnly: true
```

on the cookie, you are telling the browser that browser Javascript is not allowed to have access to the cookie, that the cookie should only be stored locally and sent to the server as required.

If you want browser Javascript to have access, then change to:

```
httpOnly: false
```

> I would like to access it in front-end (JavaScript) Is it possible?

Yes, it is possible.  Don't set `httpOnly: true`.

If you want to read about this, you can read the [MDN page on cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#Secure_and_HttpOnly_cookies) where it has this:

> To prevent cross-site scripting (XSS) attacks, HttpOnly cookies are inaccessible to JavaScript's Document.cookie API; they are only sent to the server. For example, cookies that persist server-side sessions don't need to be available to JavaScript, and the HttpOnly flag should be set.

Comment: Thank you for your help.
I have changed httpOnly false from true but still `document.cookie` is null.
`document` has only DOM tree so I guess `document.cookie` is null. Do you have some ideas?

Comment: @TomomiSakoMaeda - You'd have to show your specific client-side code.  `document.cookie` in browser Javascript will contain any cookies that are present for that domain and path and are accessible to Javascript.  It's used by millions of apps so when used correctly, it works.

Comment: @TomomiSakoMaeda - One thing I notice is that `res.cookie()` uses a `maxAge` value in **milliseconds** so when you do `maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24`, that is only 86 seconds from now.

Comment: @TomomiSakoMaeda - You can view cookies directly in the browser (in Chrome, it's via an advanced settings page) and you can see the http response directly (including the cookie) by looking in the network tab of the debugger after you request the relevant page.

Comment: @TomomiSakoMaeda - I also notice that in your current middleware code, if the "mainCookie" cookie is already present even with the older `httpOnly: true` flag on it, then your code will NOT modify it.  So, you may be stuck with the `httpOnly` flag on your current cookie until you force your code to overwrite it or until you manually delete it (or until it expires).

Comment: @ jfriend00 - Yes, your last guess was correct. I needed to delete an existing cookie before running the code again.
Now I re-create new cookie with `httpOnly:false` , and it works well. Thank you!